# Ensure the given word (string) has all upper case letters using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, pattern-matching

Given a string.

How do I check if the string has all upper letters or not?

Comment: Isn't regex just a *bit* overkill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `toUpperCase` method.

```
var text = "My text NoT Always In UPpErcAse";

text = text.toUpperCase();

text; // "MY TEXT NOT ALWAYS IN UPPERCASE"
```

EDIT:

Just realized you want to CHECK if it is in uppercase. You can do this:

```
var text = "My text NoT Always In UPpErcAse";
var text2 = "UPPERCASE!";

function isUppercased(string) {
  return string === string.toUpperCase();
}

isUppercased(text); // false
isUppercased(text2); // true
```

Comment: This doesn't test it, it forces it to uppercase even if it's not.

Comment: Sorry, just updated my post.